# Thymeleaf: Parameters In URLs Not Being Replaced

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC & Thymeleaf.  I've got the following HTML portion that prints out a link & a button:

```
<ul th:each="item : ${typesMap}">
  <li>
    <a href="roomdetails.html" th:href="@{/roomdetails/${item.key}/${item.value}}">Linky</a>
    <button type="button" th:text="${item.value}">Button Text</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the two examples, the parameters in the link are never replaced.  I always end up with something along the lines of `roomdetails/${item.key}/${item.value}` in the HTML.  The button works fine though & will show with the text that is found in ${item.value} for each iteration of the loop.

Does anyone know why I can't get URLs in the format I want? From what I can see, I'm doing what the documentation is telling me to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
<a href="roomdetails.html"  th:href="@{'/roomdetails/' + ${item.key} + '/' + ${item.value}}">
```

Comment: I still couldn't get the URLs to work with the parenthesis but the string concatenation worked at list.

Comment: @LeeTheobald Nice one, I'll remove the one above. I didn't have a dev setup to test it but I thought it might have worked from memory.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```html
<a href="roomdetails.html"  th:href="@{'/roomdetails/{paramsKey}/{paramsValue}'(paramsKey=${item.key}, paramsValue=${item.value})}">
```

I hope that this might solve your issue.